# Pass complex object through controllers (core data)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am completely lost.

The problem is passing data through viewcontrollers in my wizard.
My project contains 4 viewcontrollers:

- Step1ViewController, possibility to fill in name
- Step2ViewController, possibility to fill in nickname
- Step3ViewController, possibility to fill in emailaddress,
- Step4ViewController, possibility to fill in interests, finish

All viewcontrollers are pushed to a navigation controller. It's possible to go to the next step by clicking the bar button on the navigationtoolbar. What I want to achieve is to collect all the data in the steps and create save a NSManagedobject in the last step (by clicking the finish button). So when an user quits in step 2 and he restarts the app, there should be no saved object. So he will restart the wizard. When there is a personobject in core data then another view is loaded (this is a condition in the delegate class)

I know when you have a simple model schema passing data can be easily done to the controllers by using the prepareForSegue method. Collect all variables and create and save a core data object. For passing data back to the previous step I can use protocols.

But in my application my model schema is way more complex. My wizard contains about 18 steps and there are a lot of assiociated models for the Person model (like trainingsplan, interests, etc.) so I think collecting all data in variables and combine them all in the last step is really not a good approach.

What is the best way to do this?

I uploaded a wizard sample application with a couple of steps and 2 models (Person and interests (one-2-many)). Hopefully this will make it more clear. Feel free to modify the code: https://github.com/stalkert/WizardPrototype

Comment: Try create user coredata object on 1st step, and store it in separate class or pass it through all steps controllers. At finish you should commit it or delete.

Comment: Try saving the information in NSUserDefaults? and save al the data in CoreData when user completes the wizard? if the user quits before completing the wizard, you can clear all the saved data in NSUserDefaults. How about that?

Comment: @HarisHussain question about that: Is it possible to 'auto-map' my model schema to the NSDefaults structure? So that everything is saved in one action (with all childs: trainingsplan, interest, etc.) or should this be a manual operation?

Comment: No, i dont think of any procedure to auto-map of NSUserDefaults, but as far as your problem is concerned, you must have a finite set of values, so you can manually map them onto your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind - each has their own pros and cons. Both use the concept of a mutable dictionary that will hold all the various data that you need at the end. In addition, you will add a key='step' with an NSNumber object.

1) Assuming that all the view controllers do not exist initially, he first controller creates the dictionary, adds the data it should supply to it, and sets the 'step' to two. It then creates and runs a new viewController, passing the dictionary off to it in a property. The second verifies the step is correct, adds what it should, then passes it to another controller. The 'step' here acts as a test that in fact the dictionary is at the stage it should be.

2) Assuming the view controllers are already instantiated then use the same 'step' concept as above, but use notifications. When the first step is complete, either store the dictionary in defaults, a class or singleton object, or the appDelegate (in a property). Send out a notification - and add a userInfo that is either the full dictionary or a number providing the next step. The controller that should do step 3 can see that its turn is up so it should become active (switch a UITabBarController tab automatically etc).

In either case, when the last step is complete, send the dictionary to the class managing the repository or do it directly.